# Passing a value from an iOS device into Appium

Tags: appium

I have an iOS app (separate from the one getting tested) that generates a unique number that I want to pass into Appium. How can I achieve this?

Do I need to create a database and save the number into it, so that Appium can access it from there, or perhaps use NSUserDefaults?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your target app read the value of the value generated by the other app and have it displayed on a view.